# Ember Octane - access route's model from controller

Tags: typescript, ember.js

I am trying to make ember & typescript work together - I created a route with controller. In route's model() method I fetch data from server. I previously was able to access these data in controller via `model`, but not now. `model` attribute in controller is undefined (event though the `model()` method works correctly).

```
model() {
    return new EmberPromise((resolve, reject) => {
        //fetch data from server
        resolve(dataFromServer);
    });
}
```

Can you advise me, how to access `model` attribute in ember octane & typescript world?

thanks

Comment: How are you trying to access it in the controller?

Comment: Hi! Are you sure the model hook is in the route that corresponds to the controller?

Comment: @BuckDoyle like this: `this.model.someProperty`

Comment: ok so I stripped down my route and controller files to the bare minimum (there was some bussiness logic code in the route) + replaced the async Promise in my `model()` function with a simple return of a JSON... and everything worked. I then reverted model() function back to the previous state and in still worked. I reverted everything else... and it still works.... I cannot figure out what happened - I did git diff on these files and nothing has changed - it just works suddenly... so anyway, thanks guys ¯\_(ツ)_/¯